# I have a huge boot fail....gnome power manager

Tags: gnome, gnome-power-manager

The thing is gnome power mangager isn't working and everything is seen in crappy graphics, when I log in, the same error message appears and says something is wrong with gnome power management, it also said the xorg server has failed... true this for my Virtual Machine, but the same message appears for my desktop, the VM is more important to me :D

Answer (score 0):

If you could, could you boot into a recovery console as root and run the following command:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gnome-power-manager
```

That might work.